# When using react navigation, to hide the parent component header button from the child component?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

Stack navigation is parent and tab navigation is child

I want to hide the button when I press the "settings" tab.

using `react-navigation ver.5

please help me.

**child**

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const Tabs = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Observatory" component={Observatory} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={Search} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Setting" component={Setting} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

**parent**

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Tabs"
          component={Tabs}
          options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
            headerRight: () => (
              <Icon
                name="edit"
                size={30}
                color="#000"
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Template')}
              />
            ),
          })}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Template" component={Template} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: You want to hide the header ONLY for the Settings Tab or, hide the header for ALL tabs in the TabNavigator?

Comment: Hello~ ONLY for the Settings Tab